# what's the proper use of gestures in Monster Hunter?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I'm using the gestures just for fun so far, but I've noticed that some food boosts affect some gestures, for example the shadowbox.
So I think there's another functions for the gestures, not only for looking cool or skilled.

Comment: I believe in one of the older ones, waving at the hot air balloon would cause it to spot the monster on the map for you.  Not sure this was kept in the later editions.

Comment: I thought that I would use gestures to interact with Cha-cha.

Comment: Waving at the balloon for Oracle works in MH3U and MH4U.

Comment: I didn't see this balloon so far …

Answer (score 2):

- If you see a hot air balloon in the sky, waving at it will locate large monsters on your map for a short duration. (MH3U does not have this feature)
- Shadowbox and Taunt will deal very slight damage.
- Kick Back will give you a small attack boost if you got Cool Cat when eating before the quest.

None of the others do anything special, though you can use them to communicate with other players online.